# Xamarin.Forms. Как сделать анимацию Slide show & Fade для поиска?

Tags: анимация, xamarin, search

У меня есть компонент:

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="grid">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Entry Grid.Row="0" x:Name="textField" Keyboard="Text" BackgroundColor="#a6ffffff" />

  <Image Source="Search.png" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" WidthRequest="25" HeightRequest="25">
       <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Image_Tapped" />
      </Image.GestureRecognizers>
  </Image>
```

Этот компонент располагается в AbsoluteLayout в правом углу. Когда я нажимаю на картинку, то мой объект выезжает справа налево. Но работает он дёргано. 
Вот моя анимация:

```
void Image_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var img = sender as Image;

  var animation = new Animation();

  var textFieldTranslate = new Animation(v => textField.TranslationX = v, img.Width img.Width - 300);
  var textFieldChangeWidth = new Animation(v => textField.WidthRequest = v, 0, 300);

  animation.Add(0, 1, textFieldTranslate);
  animation.Add(0, 1, textFieldChangeWidth);

  animation.Commit(this, "Slide", 1000, 500, Easing.Linear);
}
```

Как это можно исправить? Как добиться плавности?

Ниже приведён пример анимации. Панель выезжает справа налево.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может есть иные решения данной задачи?

А также после того как анимация отработала, Entry не реагирует на тап. С чем это может быть связано и как исправить?

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0"
                Padding="{StaticResource ContentPagePadding}" BackgroundColor="#000017">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="9*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="1" Padding="5, 0" />

            <AbsoluteLayout>
                <Image Source="logo.png" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".1, 0, .3, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />

                <Image Source="bookmark.png" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".8, .5, .1, .4" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" >
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{TemplateBinding BookmarkCommand}" />
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>

                <AbsoluteLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".9, .4, .1, .4" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                    <ctrl:SearchView />
                </AbsoluteLayout>
            </AbsoluteLayout>
        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я создал компонент HeaderView:

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <FlexLayout Direction="RowReverse" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".1, .5, .9, .5" 
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
        <ctrl:ExtendedEntry x:Name="textField"
                            Style="{StaticResource SearchEntryStyle}"
                            Placeholder="{ext:Translate Search_placeholder}"
                            TextChanged="Handle_TextChanged" />
    </FlexLayout>

    <Image Source="Search.png" x:Name="image"
           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".9, .5, .1, .4" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Image_Tapped" />
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

C#:

```
void AnimationIn()
{
    textField.IsVisible = true;
    image.Source = "Search_active.png";

    new Animation(v => textField.WidthRequest = v, 0, EntryWidth)
        .Commit(this, "SlideIn", 1000, ANIMATION_TIME, Easing.CubicIn);
}

void AnimationOut()
{
    new Animation(v => textField.WidthRequest = v, EntryWidth, 0)
        .Commit(this, "SlideOut", 1000, ANIMATION_TIME, Easing.CubicOut);

    image.Source = "Search.png";
}
```